# create objects from nested JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
"E01": {
    "AdvisorService": [                
        "raw/18_c.txt",
        "raw/33_c.txt"
    ],
    "Workfile": "raw/39_c.txt",
    "DigitalImage": ["raw/41_c.txt"],   // List of images in different XMLs
    "Event": [                          // List of events in different XMLs
        "raw/44_c.txt",
        "raw/59_c.txt",
        "raw/60_c.txt",
        "raw/63_c.txt",
        "raw/64_c.txt",
        "raw/65_c.txt",
        "raw/66_c.txt",
        "raw/67_c.txt",
        "raw/68_c.txt",
        "raw/69_c.txt"
    ],
    "StatusChange": "raw/73_c.txt",
    "EstimatePrintImage": "raw/40_c.txt",
    "UnrelatedPriorDamage": "raw/42_c.txt",
    "RelatedPriorDamageReport": "raw/43_c.txt"
},
"S01": "... similar structure as above"
```

}

How do I create objects such as these: (Assume XMLBase is the base class for all these objects)

1)
(2 objects of type AdvisorService as there are 2 items in the list)

```
type('AdvisorService', (XMLBase,), {'file_loc': 'raw/18_c.txt', 'estimate_type': 'E01'})
type('AdvisorService', (XMLBase,), {'file_loc': 'raw/33_c.txt', 'estimate_type': 'E01'})
```

2)
(1 object of type Workfile as it has 1 value)

```
type('Workfile', (XMLBase,), {'file_loc': 'raw/39_c.txt', 'estimate_type': 'E01'})
```

3)
(1 object of type DigitalImage as it has 1 value)

```
type('DigitalImage', (XMLBase,), {'file_loc': 'raw/41_c.txt', 'estimate_type': 'E01'})
```

4)
(10 objects of type Event as it has 10 values)

```
type('Event', (XMLBase,), {'file_loc': 'raw/44_c.txt', 'estimate_type': 'E01'})
... so on
```

5) So on

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The code you show makes a new class for each leaf in your `JSON`, but I have no idea why you'd want that or what problem you might have doing it.

Comment: My requirement is that I have a bunch of SOAP request XML files for each of the endpoints I am going to hit viz, AdvisorService, Workfile etc, along with their location in my directory. This is the structure I represented in my JSON above. I am creating classes for each of these request types and sending them over http to their respective SOAP endpoints in my downstream code. Any idea to improve this whole design is welcome. Thanks.